# notification click render only my domain url not my click_action key url in as i pass in my payload for mobile devices onmessage event

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
     onmessgae event code --
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
        const notificationOptions = {
            body: payload.notification.body,
            icon: payload.notification.icon,
            data: payload.notification.click_action,
        };
         navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js');
        if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            // If it's okay let's create a notification
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
                    registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
            })
        }
    })


my notification click event -
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  var default_val  = 0;
  console.log(event.notification)
  event.notification.close();
    try{
        url  = event.notification.data.FCM_MSG.notification.click_action
        console.log("check1")
       console.log("true")
    }
    catch (err) {
        url = event.notification.data
        console.log("check2")

           }
          //url = event.notification.data
           if (default_val ==0) {
               default_val = default_val+1
               event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(url));

           }
})

my payload ---

{"notification": 
{"body": "testing", "click_action": "/order1/", "icon": "http://localhost:8000/static/Logo/fcm_logo.jpg", "mutable-content": 1, "title": "hi "},
```

i am implementing fcm services for my project ,as i maintain in my titile i am getting a problem with my onmessage event in mobile devices .i sharing some code  ,my setBackgroundMessageHandler event is working fine for both mobile or desktop version ...but issue with on message event in mobile devices